# in_array not working correctly

Tags: php, arrays

I am using in array to try and load a specific dropdown but I am unsure why its not working - I am getting no data from `shop_shipping_rule_item_multiple`

**Array:**

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        ["shop_shipping_rule_name"]=> string(13) "Overnight UPS"
        ["shop_shipping_rule_item_multiple"]=> string(4) "4.00"
        ["shop_shipping_rule_type_multi"]=> string(5) "multi"
    }
    [1]=> array(3) {
        ["shop_shipping_rule_name"]=> string(13) "NZ Snail Mail"
        ["shop_shipping_rule_item_multiple"]=> string(5) "35.00"
        ["shop_shipping_rule_type_multi"]=> string(5) "multi"
    }
}
```

**Code:**

```
<?php foreach($shipping_methods as $method): ?>
    <?php if(in_array('shop_shipping_rule_type_multi', $method)): ?>

            <option onchange="calShipping()" value="<?php echo $method['shop_shipping_rule_item_multiple'];?>"><?php echo $method['shop_shipping_rule_name'];?> | <?php echo $method['shop_shipping_rule_item_multiple']; ?></option>

        <?php else: ?>
            <option onchange="calShipping()" value="<?php echo $method['shop_shipping_rule_item_single'];?>"><?php echo $method['shop_shipping_rule_name'];?> | <?php echo $method['shop_shipping_rule_item_single']; ?></option>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: `in_array` is for lists, not nested arrays. It also looks at values, not keys.

Comment: I think you need `array_key_exists()` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current me if I am wrong, since you are checking for a key in an array you might want to take a look at *array_key_exists* function
Source: https://www.php.net/array_key_exists

i.e.

```
array_key_exists('shop_shipping_rule_type_multi', $method)
```

in_array checks if a value exist in a given array

Comment: :) I had to wait for my time to be up